# GWT weird onblur handler behaviour

Tags: java, gwt

Hi i am using focus and blur handlers for a flow panel to add outlines. However, i am getting some weird behavior given the code :

```
            panel.addDomHandler(new FocusHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onFocus(FocusEvent focusEvent) {
                    panel.addStyleName("FOOSTYLE");
                }
            }, FocusEvent.getType());


            panel.addDomHandler(new BlurHandler() {
                FlowPanel _panel = focusPanel;
                boolean init = false;
                @Override
                public void onBlur(BlurEvent blurEvent) {
                    console.log("Do Blur");
                    panel.removeStyleName("FOOSTYLE");
                }
            }, BlurEvent.getType());
```

The removeStyleName() in the blur handler seems to be called for no reason, also note the log, it's not even executed when the random blur handler gets called, if ever it was.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To handle focus and blur events you should use [`FocusPanel`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html). It implements [`HasFocusHandlers`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasFocusHandlers.html) and [`HasBlurHandlers`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasBlurHandlers.html) so you can call `addFocusHandler()` and `addBlurHandler()` instead of low-level `addDomHandler()` method.

If you need to use `FlowPanel` to lay out your widgets you can add it to the `FocusPanel`.

Comment: I tried that before, made no difference, removeStyleName still gets called for no reason at all.